# Run VBA automation for pulling internetexplorer source data in background

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

I work in an engine maintenance department and for alot of our big projects (i.e. diesel engine rebuilds) we have to request alot of parts through our inventory intranet site. all of our parts have an assigned identification/catalog number. Unfortunately the site only lets you search for one part at a time. I created this macro to speed up the process and check our inventory for all catalog numbers I enter into the spreadsheet.

I wrote a macro in VBA that would access the site, use the catalog numbers (I have entered in the A-Column of my worksheet) and plug it into the search inventory page. My Macro would then retrieve the part description, manufacturer part number, number available, number on order and return it to my spreadsheet.

In order for this macro to work I pretty much have to leave my computer alone until the whole process is finished (i.e. no opening up any new windows, no minimizing the macro-opened internet explorer...)

I was wondering if there's any way to make it so that I can use my computer while this macro is running through its thing.

```
Sub ICSsearch()
Range("A2").Select
Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
'Go to this Web Page!
    IE.navigate "http://dd2.deepwater.com/t-sso-v206/sso/logon.aspx?baseurl=http://dd2.deepwater.com/ics/home.aspx"
'Check for good connection to web page loop!
Do
  If IE.readyState = 4 Then
  IE.Visible = True   
Exit Do
Else
  DoEvents
End If
Loop

'Wait for window to open!
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
IE.Visible = True

'Send logon information
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
SendKeys "ENTER USERNAME", True
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
SendKeys "ENTER PASSWORD", True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
SendKeys "{Enter}", True

'Go to this Web Page for Search Inventory (also start of search loop)!
Do
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
IE.navigate "http://dd2.deepwater.com/ics/stocksearch.aspx"

'Enter ICN number
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
IE.Document.getelementbyid("ctl05_TextBoxSCN").Value = Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row))
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
SendKeys "{Enter}", True

'Extract ICS Results
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Range("B" & (ActiveCell.Row)) = IE.Document.getelementbyid("ctl05_LabelPartNumber").innerText
Range("C" & (ActiveCell.Row)) = IE.Document.getelementbyid("ctl05_LabelDescription").innerText
Range("D" & (ActiveCell.Row)) = IE.Document.getelementbyid("ctl05_LabelUsableQty").innerText
Range("E" & (ActiveCell.Row)) = IE.Document.getelementbyid("ctl05_LabelOnOrderQuantity").innerText

Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

If Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = "" Then
Exit Do
Else
DoEvents
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we using "SendKeys" Method system wont allow you to work.. Instead you can find out your site UserName and PassWord input box ids or Name and the use below code.

```
IE.Document.getElementByID("YourIDID").value = UserName
IE.Document.getelementByID("YouPWDID").vlaue = PWD
IE.Document.getelementByID("ButtonID").click
```

By using this way there is no dependency between excel and other applications so you can use your system.

If you use send key there is a possibility it can type anywhere instead of input box.

Answer (score 0):

This is done in IE Window only, you can use your computer?

```
'
' Do IE wait: waiting for IE query return:
' inputs:
'   objIe: IE object
'
Function sofDoIeWait(ByVal objIe)
  While (objIe.Busy Or objIe.readyState <> 4)
    DoEvents
  Wend
  sofDoIeWait = 1
End Function

Sub sof20160137ICSsearch()
  Dim iRow As Long, IE As Object
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Visible = True
  'Go to this Web Page!
  IE.navigate "http://dd2.deepwater.com/t-sso-v206/sso/logon.aspx?baseurl=http://dd2.deepwater.com/ics/home.aspx"
  'Check for good connection to web page loop!
  sofDoIeWait IE

'Wait for window to open!
' Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
' IE.Visible = True

'Send logon information
' Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
  SendKeys "ENTER USERNAME", True
  SendKeys "{TAB}", True
  SendKeys "ENTER PASSWORD", True
' Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
  SendKeys "{Enter}", True

  sofDoIeWait IE
'
' now we are logged in, so go to the search page:
'
  IE.navigate "http://dd2.deepwater.com/ics/stocksearch.aspx"
  sofDoIeWait IE
'
  Range("A2").Select
  iRow = ActiveCell.Row
'
'Go to this Web Page for Search Inventory (also start of search loop)!
'
  Do
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    'Enter ICN number
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    '
    ' do search the value of the ActiveCell:
    '
    IE.Document.getElementById("ctl05_TextBoxSCN").Value = Range("A" & iRow)
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    SendKeys "{Enter}", True
    sofDoIeWait IE
    '
    'Extract ICS Results
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    '
    Range("B" & iRow) = IE.Document.getElementById("ctl05_LabelPartNumber").innerText
    Range("C" & iRow) = IE.Document.getElementById("ctl05_LabelDescription").innerText
    Range("D" & iRow) = IE.Document.getElementById("ctl05_LabelUsableQty").innerText
    Range("E" & iRow) = IE.Document.getElementById("ctl05_LabelOnOrderQuantity").innerText

    Range("A" & iRow).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    iRow = ActiveCell.Row

    If Range("A" & iRow).Value = "" Then
      Exit Do
    Else
      DoEvents
    End If
  Loop
End Sub
```